# how to publish int8,float ...and function?

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i can't publish int8 .. can you help me?

```
  #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int8.h"

#include <sstream>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

 
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("mytopic", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    int8_t count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
   
    std_msgs::Int8 msg;

  
    msg.data = count++;

    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data);

    
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();
    
  }


  return 0;
}
```

display : `NULL`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192537/how-to-publish-int8,float-...and-function-?/) by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data);
```

For `std_msgs::Int8`, the `data` field is of the `int8` type (see the [msg doc](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int8.html)). The `%s` format string is for strings (or `char*`), so that won't work. Try `%d`.

---

PS: are you sure you aren't ignoring some compiler warning?

PPS: the question title says you cannot publish an `Int8`, but in your actual question it would seem you only have difficulty logging the `data` field using `ROS_INFO(..)`. Perhaps you should update the title to reflect your actual issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on 2014-09-12**:
Thanhk you ! i done

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ROS_INFO("%d", msg.data);  // msg.data is int data type so %d
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1